# Troubles converting a string of binary numbers into a character string

Tags: python-3.x, binary, signal-processing

I am working on improving my programming. This is a toy problem I created that takes in a string converts it to a binary form to be sent as a signal. The signal is then received and decoded. Eventually, I wanted to add noise to practice filtering.

This is my transmitter function:

```
def transmitter(msg):
    Z = []
    pulse_msg = ''
    for x in msg:
        pulse_msg = pulse_msg + ''.join(format(ord(x),'b'))
        print(len(pulse_msg))

    for x in pulse_msg:
        Z.append(x)
        #print(Z)
    t = range(len(Z))
    #plt.plot(t,Z)    
    return(Z)
```

This is my receiver function:

```
def rec(msg):
    A = ''.join(msg)
    Y = []
    i = 1
    while i < len(A):
        Y.append(A[i-1:6+i])
        i +=7
    return(A)

z = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']

A = rec(z)
print(A)
```

I am having the problem in the receiver. The value of Y is a list of the original letters in binary form, but I can't understand how to translate that into a character. I have tried using the binascii function, but either I used it incorrectly or it doesn't work due to the values in Y being a string. In this test z = 'hello world'. Let me know if I can clear anything up. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems

1. Your transmitter function is dropping leading zeroes of the bytes.  That means that some of your letters are shorter than others, making them impossible to translate.  You should be doing something like `'{:08b}'.format(ord(x))` to get 8-width zero padded bitstrings.
2. You should be using the `chr` function to turn `int`s back into characters.  Happily, we can use the `int` function to translate bitstrings into integers like this `chr(int('01101000', 2)) == 'h'`.  (2 is the base of the string that is being converted to an integer).